# Floating point math accuracy, c++ vs fortran

Tags: c++, fortran

I have tried to implement a recursive function, in both C++ and Fortran, which calculates the value of the n'th Legendre polynomial, at x. In Fortran I have

```
recursive function legendre(n, x) result(p)
  integer, intent(in) :: n
  real(8), intent(in) :: x
  real(8) :: p

  if(n == 0) then
    p = 1.0
  else if (n == 1) then
    p = x
  else
    p = (2.0*real(n,dp)-1.0)*x*legendre(n-1,x)-(real(n,dp)-1.0)*legendre(n-2,x)
    p = p / real(n,dp)
  end if 
end function legendre
```

and then in C++ I have

```
double legendre(int n, double x) {
  double p;
  if(n == 0) return 1.0;
  else if(n == 1) return x;
  else {
    p = (2.0*(double)n - 1.0)*x*legendre(n-1,x)-((double)n - 1.0)*legendre(n-2,x);
    p /= (double)n;
    return p;
  }
}
```

These two functions seem to be exactly the same to me, both using double precission, but the result from the Fortran function is substantial different from the C++ result. For example,
legendre(7,-0.2345) = 0.28876207107499049178814404296875 according to WolframAlpha. The two codes above, when compiled with no optimizations produce

Fortran : 0.28876206852410113

C++ : 0.28876207107499052285

I know that the answers should not be the same due to floating point arithmetic, but the difference in value here for double precision seems somewhat large to me. What is the reason that the Fortran value is so far off from the other two ?

Comment: It's a **very** long time since I worked in FORTRAN but, IIRC, you need a `D` in floating-point constants to make them double-precision. (In C++, they are `double` by default.) Could this be the issue?

Comment: You may well have tried this already, but can't you run the two side by side with line by line debuggers, and watch the divergence? Does `real(n,dp)` return a `double`? I haven't used fortran since FORTRAN 77 (with while loop extension). I'm asking all this as the difference seems to be in the order of magnitude of  `float` vv. `double` precision.

Comment: I forgot to change a part of my code, dp=8 in the fortran code. That is just the kind value required on my system for double precision.

Comment: Please show complete examples for your code.  In particular, the constant `dp` is not declared here (and potentially affects the result) and the function calls are not shown.

Comment: Given that you answered with "Nothing was wrong with the code in the Fortran function", please, really do make the example complete: see [mre].

Answer (score 5):

Although the *variables* in your `FORTRAN` function are defined as double-precision (8 bytes), the *constants* you have specified are default (single-precision, 4-byte) values.

According to [this discussion](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler/topic/506685), that means the arithmetic is performed to single-precision accuracy:

> Even if the variable that you are assigning the result to is defined
>   to be DP, the Fortran standard ***requires*** that the arithmetic on the
>   constants be performed using SP. That is because you are using default
>   real constants, since you do not have any kind type parameter at the
>   end of the constants.  By rule, default real is SP.

And, further on in the same discussion:

> ...Starting with Fortran 90, published in June 1991, this practice of
>   "promoting" SP constants to DP is prohibited.

So, in order to force double-precision maths, specify the constants as DP: instead of, for example, `1.0`, specify `1.0D0` (and so forth for the others).

Comment: Thanks Adrian. This did not actually fix the problem, but lead me in the right direction. It is actually because of the value x which I was passing to the function.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Adrian's response, I was able to fix the problem. Nothing was wrong with the code in the Fortran function, the issue was the value of x which I was passing to it. Even though in the main program, I had defined x as real(8) and latter assigned it the value with a simple

```
x = -0.2345
```

which I thought should be double precision. It should actually be

```
x = -0.2345_dp
```

This results in the two functions having the same answer. I believe it is likely due to the reason that Adrian pointed out.

Comment: You do need to specify `p = 1.0d0` otherwise the compiler *might* add random digits beyond the precision of `real`, unless you have specified `Extend the Precision of Real Constants` in the compile options.